# Jersey, JPA and other annotations issues when using jdk11

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, java-11

I am trying to upgrade our working softwares (j2EE) REST (jersey), JPA (eclipse link) and JAX-B from jdk8 to jdk11

I have not found yet an easy process for all our needs. I did not find either a reference document for doing an easy and soft migration. We were using netbeans (ant) and sometimes Maven.

Can you help me with some good references let says for all j2EE dependencies using netbeans 10?.

We mostly use Tomcat 9, Jersey, eclipselink, Xml and Jason.

**OR** it is better to wait a little before switching to JDK11?

Comment: What kind of problems have you encountered?